# Create UIImage from CIImage on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I was trying to rebuild a Titanium Module for iOS10 (https://github.com/Exygy/Titanium-Ti.Barcode)

While rebuilding, I am getting following error and the build is failing.

```
cannot initialize a variable of type 'UIImage *' with an rvalue of type
  'CIImage *'
UIImage *image = [blob image];
         ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Following is the piece of code where it is getting generated:

```
id blob = [args valueForKey:@"image"];
ENSURE_TYPE(blob, TiBlob);
UIImage* image = [blob image];
```

I am a noob in the Objective C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following :

Objective C:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [blob image];
UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
```

Swift 4.0:

```
let ciImage: CIImage? = blob.image()
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
 func convertCIImagetoUIimage(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
        return image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

CIImage to UIImage

Swift 3.0

```
let uiImage = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 4.0**

```
let ciImage: CIImage? = blob.image()
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage!)
```